# Sass/Scss to Stylus converter?

Tags: sass, stylus

Is there any tools to convert SASS/SCSS to Stylus?

Or any way to speed up compiling SCSS?

Comment: "any way to speed up compiling XXX" -> throw some hardware at it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I doubt there are any direct tools available, but you can do this:

Convert SASS to CSS

```
sass input.scss -o output.css
```

Then convert CSS to Stylus

```
stylus --css output.css input.styl
```

### Update

One line conversion

```
sass input.scss | stylus --css
```

Answer (score 28):

[MojoTech](http://www.mojotech.com) made a tool to easily convert SASS to Stylus:

http://sass2stylus.com/

You can view the [source code on Github](https://github.com/mojotech/sass2stylus/) if you'd like to see how it works.

Comment: This will also preserve functions, mixins, variables, etc., whereas converting to css then to stylus would lose that.

Comment: And also would not make you install SASS and Ruby as to use the CLI